# ASP.NET Form with jQuery dialogs, validate the dialog but NOT the parent form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

My ASP.NET form has a small number of modal pop-up helper dialogs on it.  We are using jQuery dialogs for these.  I need to perform some validations on the fields on the modal, before the data in the modal is transferred back to a summary field on the parent form.

As it is, if I enter everything fine on the modal, but (say) have not yet entered some required field on the parent, the modal will not submit, and error messages appear on the page behind the modal.

My guess is I am going to need to change my `<asp:LinkButton>` on the modal to `CausesValidation="false"` and add an `OnClientClick` handler to perform all these validations via jQuery, and remove all my ASP validators.  Fortunately, said validation is relatively simple.

Howeever, if there is some ASP trick that I can take advantage of here, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Did you try using validationgroups ?

Comment: Validation groups is the answer, but I didn't know about them and no searching turned this up.  @Sundeep, if you make it an answer, I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation Groups allows to validate the group of controls instead of validating all controls on the page.